# Convergence of improper integrals $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f^{2}(x)dx$

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

(1) Convergence of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx$. 
(2) Convergence of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f^{2}(x)dx$

What is the relationship betweeen the two? 
(i,e is there any logical relations...?) (1 implies 2 or 2 implies 1)

Comment: if $f$ is bounded, then (2) $\implies$ (1), since it implies that $\int |f|$ converges.

Comment: @Riccardo Orlando I think (1) => (2) is right regardless of additional conditions.. Is this right?

Comment: Those integrals are definitely definite

Comment: @user329410 well, no... $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ converges, but $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x}$ does not... I'm pretty sure this also breaks with edges $-\infty$ and $+\infty$

Comment: @Riccardo Orlando I think (2) implies (1) because the convergence of f^2 implies that f is bounded...

Comment: Well, no, it doesn't. For example, take $\int _{-1} ^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$: it converges, and the function is the square of $\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{x}}$ which is not bounded in that interval. You can extend all fo them to $\pm \infty$ by bringing them to zero with a line and then setting them identically 0.